# How to add a saved survey tab?

Tags: surveyjs

We have our surveys saving to our database, but we need to know how to add a tab in survey-creator in surveyJs. The tab we want would display saved surveys. I can't find documentation on this, and feel like it's such a simple thing it would be a shame if it's been overlooked.